# Set a image in div with javascript, using backgroundImage

Tags: javascript

i have a `<img>` with a static and zoomable image loaded.

i have a function where update some component everytime detect scrollwheel event and calculate the image width and height, after set the style properties in img element, finally set the src in result `<div>`

instead of enlarging the image, the image is moving to the side in result div.

function:

```
function updateBgStyle() {
            //alert('updateBgStyle');
            if (bgPosX > 0) {
                bgPosX = 0;
            } else if (bgPosX < width - bgWidth) {
                bgPosX = width - bgWidth;
            }

            if (bgPosY > 0) {
                bgPosY = 0;
            } else if (bgPosY < height - bgHeight) {
                bgPosY = height - bgHeight;
            }

            img.style.backgroundSize = bgWidth+'px '+bgHeight+'px';
            img.style.backgroundPosition = bgPosX+'px '+bgPosY+'px';

            var x = document.getElementById('myimage');
            var img2 = document.createElement("IMG");

            img2.src = '../../RESOURCES/images/remoteAgent/473_180420160608_HJF4013_2.jpg';

            //var oldImg = document.getElementById('myimage');
            document.getElementById('myresult').style.backgrounSize = img.style.backgroundSize;
            document.getElementById('myresult').style.backgroundPosition = img.style.backgroundPosition;
            document.getElementById('myresult').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img2.src + "')";

        }
```

xhtml:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1" style="border: 2px solid white;float: right;
    border: 2px solid white;">
    <script>
        // Initiate zoom effect:
        //imageZoom("myimage", "myresult"); 
        wheelzoom(document.querySelector('img.zoom'));

    </script>
    <img class="zoom" id="myimage" onmouseout="atualizaImg()"
        src="../../RESOURCES/images/remoteAgent/473_180420160608_HJF4013_2.jpg"
                            style=" width: 340px; margin-top: 20px;"/>

    <div id="myresult" src="../../RESOURCES/images/remoteAgent/bolaVerde.png"
        style="width: 340px;height: 200px; align: center; border: 1px solid black;"/>   
    </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Maybe it not the cause but you wrote `backgrounSize` instead of  `backgroundSize`.

Comment: Hey Camilo, i haven't seen it! Is working now! Thanks